# Socket.IO accepts non-existing src tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm doing some 'Get started thing' on Socket.IO and I noticed there was a step where I had to add the socket.io.js script to the HTML page. It said the following:

```
/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

In in my folders however, socket.io.js is at the following path:

```
/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js
```

There location socket.io doesn't exist in the root of the directory. Why exactly is it then that the first path works but the second doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

The server-side socket.io code installs a nodejs route handler for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` so that it can serve the socket.io.js file from its real location when `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is requested by a browser.

Remember, nodejs does not serve any local files automatically.  It only serves files that are processed by some sort of route or handler.  There is no route for `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js` so if a browser requests that, it won't serve anything.